# Java JDK Not Enough Space

Tags: java, space, disk

How much space do I need to install jdk1.8.0 x64windows?
(I run on windows 10)
Also, can you install jdk on an external drive like an sd card or usb drive?

Comment: For me, it takes 479 MB for jdk1.8.0_102. And yes, you can install it on a drive other than C:, just make sure to correctly modify the PATH variable after the installation so it points to the right directory.

Comment: OK phew! im glad you answered. i have a laptop with 32gb of space total sooo... yeah tiny space.

Comment: My condolences. And I suffer from having only 256GB on mine... (default HP Recovery drive and a partition for my ubuntu dualboot included)

Comment: wow... 256 gb for me is a TON!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JDK 1.8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) takes below 500MB (half a gig).

Yes, it can be installed into another external drive.

Comment: thats weird because i tried installing it on C: and i had 600 mb availible but it still said that i didnt have enought space... oh well ill install it on E: